# What is the will of the Father according to the LDS vewpoint?

Tags: soteriology, lds, will-of-god

> #### True and False Disciples
>
> 21 “Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but only the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven. 22 Many will say to me on that day, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in your name and in your name drive out demons and in your name perform many miracles?’ 23 Then I will tell them plainly, ‘I never knew you. Away from me, you evildoers!’   MATTHEW 7:21-23

Jesus is here stating that many will attempt to justify themselves according to what they have done (verse 22); but He clearly says it is only those who do His will who will be saved.

The Bible clearly says that the will of God is:

> #### John 6:38-40
>
> For I have come down from heaven, not to do my own will but the will of him who sent me. And this is the will of him who sent me, that I should lose nothing of all that he has given me, but raise it up on the last day. *For this is the will of my Father, that everyone who looks on the Son and believes in him should have eternal life,* and I will raise him up on the last day.”

Therefore; what will the Mormon faithful say to Jesus when at the "pearly gates" so to speak...why should he let you in to the kingdom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not just one answer to this, but rather a combination of many things that we do to allow us to be "swallowed up in the will of the Father." What will allow us to enter the "Pearly Gates" is our actions and the direction we are heading. If we strive to do our best, it will allow the Atonement of Jesus Christ to cleanse us so we can enter therein.

Scripturally I think these verses help us to understand how we can submit ourselves to the Father's will. We must become like Jesus Christ as  1 John 3:2-3 explains:

> 2 Beloved, now are we the sons of God, and it doth not yet appear what we shall be: but we know that, when he shall appear, we shall be like him; for we shall see him as he is.
>
> 3 And every man that hath this hope in him purifieth himself, even as he is pure.

and within the Book of Mormon, [Moroni 7:47-48](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/moro/7.47-48),

> 47 But charity is the pure love of Christ, and it endureth forever; and whoso is found possessed of it at the last day, it shall be well with him.
>
> 48 Wherefore, my beloved brethren, pray unto the Father with all the energy of heart, that ye may be filled with this love, which he hath bestowed upon all who are true followers of his Son, Jesus Christ; that ye may become the sons of God; that when he shall appear we shall be like him, for we shall see him as he is; that we may have this hope; that we may be purified even as he is pure. Amen.

After a great sermon was given by the Prophet King Benjamin, in the Book of Mormon, his people said the [following](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/mosiah/5.2?lang=eng#1):

> 2 And they all cried with one voice, saying: Yea, we believe all the words which thou hast spoken unto us; and also, we know of their surety and truth, because of the Spirit of the Lord Omnipotent, which has wrought a mighty change in us, or in our hearts, that we have no more disposition to do evil, but to do good continually.

These individuals were changed by the Word of God, so much so they had no more desire to do evil and were will to subject themselves to the Will of the Father.

> 5 And we are willing to enter into a covenant with our God to do his will, and to be obedient to his commandments in all things that he shall command us, all the remainder of our days, that we may not bring upon ourselves a never-ending torment, as has been spoken by the angel, that we may not drink out of the cup of the wrath of God.

King Benjamin was thrilled, as this was the reaction he wanted:

> 7 And now, because of the covenant which ye have made ye shall be called the children of Christ, his sons, and his daughters; for behold, this day he hath spiritually begotten you; for ye say that your hearts are changed through faith on his name; therefore, ye are born of him and have become his sons and his daughters.
>
> 8 And under this head ye are made free, and there is no other head whereby ye can be made free. There is no other name given whereby salvation cometh; therefore, I would that ye should take upon you the name of Christ, all you that have entered into the covenant with God that ye should be obedient unto the end of your lives.
>
> 9 And it shall come to pass that whosoever doeth this shall be found at the right hand of God, for he shall know the name by which he is called; for he shall be called by the name of Christ.

We will not be allowed to enter the "Pearly Gates" of Heaven *just* because we belong to The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints. It takes purification and sanctification by the Power of the Atonment of Christ.

The Prophet [Alma taught](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/alma/34.32?lang=eng):

> 32 For behold, this life is the time for men to prepare to meet God; yea, behold the day of this life is the day for men to perform their labors.
>
> 33 And now, as I said unto you before, as ye have had so many witnesses, therefore, I beseech of you that ye do not procrastinate the day of your repentance until the end; for after this day of life, which is given us to prepare for eternity, behold, if we do not improve our time while in this life, then cometh the night of darkness wherein there can be no labor performed.

I would recommend you read the first bullet point under additional reading, this is the most recent sermon on this topic, given by an Apostle of the Lord.

Additional Reading:

- [David A Bednar: If Ye Had Known Me, 2016](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/2016/10/if-ye-had-known-me?lang=eng)
- [Neal A Maxwell: Swallowed up in the will of the father, 1995](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/1995/10/swallowed-up-in-the-will-of-the-father?lang=eng)
- [Submitting our Will to the Father's, 2004](https://www.lds.org/ensign/2004/07/book-of-mormon-principles-submitting-our-will-to-the-fathers?lang=eng)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed STAPLES sir.  A fantastic and swift answer.  I must admit I am surprised by my own fascination into the LDS viewpoint; hence why I ask such questions. upon thus superb site.  I have marked your answer as accepted; Thank you for your time in responding.

Comment: STAPLES; the sermon found in your recommendation {David A Bednar: If Ye Had Known Me, 2016} is spot on for my question; thank you.

Comment: @David awesome! I am glad it answered your question!

Comment: @David www.mormon.org is also a great place to have questions answered

Answer (score 1):

I think this link probably best expresses the LDS view of the Will of the Father.

https://www.lds.org/ensign/2004/07/book-of-mormon-principles-submitting-our-will-to-the-fathers?lang=eng

Answer (score 0):

It is the Mormon belief that there are many "levels" of the Celestial Kingdom. In this way, the afterlife is not a binary choice between Heaven and Hell. Instead, we find eternal reward in proportion to our righteousness.

John 14:2 comes to mind:

> In my Father's house are many mansions: if it were not so, I would
>   have told you. I go to prepare a place for you.

In fact, by my understanding, Hell -- or Outer Darkness, as we more often refer to it -- is reserved for those that do abhorrent acts, without ever repenting of them.

By confessing and forsaking our sins, and coming unto God with a "broken heart and a contrite spirit," though our sins be as scarlet, we will be pure as the driven snow.

We have the ability to receive personal revelation through prayer and meditation. By reading the scriptures and asking God what his will is on a daily basis, we can each receive answers and learn how to act as one of His unique instruments.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer here. It would be improved if you could add some quotes or references to Mormon materials supporting your statements here. See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/20394) For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: Much of this is based on my memories of what I was taught as a deacon, teacher, priest, and finally elder in the Mormon church. It should not be taken to be a definitive statement of doctrine.

Comment: That said, I will try to find sources that support my recollections.

Comment: @DJG, "Hell" would be anything less than the highest degree of the Celestial Kingdom, the point at which we are no longer damned from eternal progression.  The Telestial kingdom is filled with those who were unrepentant.  Outer Darkness (filled with the Sons of Perdidtion) is reserved for those with a perfect knowledge of God and His Christ and willfully rebells against Them. [Doc. & Cov. 76](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76.1-119?lang=eng#0)